# strptime: time data does not match format

Tags: python, jython

Using Jython, a Java implementation of Python, I am unable to figure out why a date will not match a format in en_AU but it will in en_US.

```
ValueError: time data u'Fri Mar 5 08:00:00 2010' does not match format u'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'
```

Source:

```
time.strptime(value)
```

When tested using Python (not Jython) in both en_US and en_AU, the date parses as expected:

```
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time;
>>> time.strptime("Fri Mar 5 08:00:00 2010", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=5, tm_hour=8, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=64, tm_isdst=-1)
```

It also works fine with en_US on Jython. However, if the computer's language is en_AU, then Jython cannot parse the date and the error above is thrown.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a bug in Jython caused by JDK 9/11/12/+ and a lack of locale support in Jython:

https://bugs.jython.org/issue2730

Hopefully this will be fixed soon.